# JSON Schema / Formly dependent sub-schemas

Tags: json, jsonschema, angular-formly, ngx-formly

This issue is a bit tricky to describe so bear with me and please ask questions if I am missing anything...

Say you have a json object that defines a list of features, each feature has a the same three properties but has a property that has an entirely different structure. For example:

```
{
  features: [
    {
       id: "feature-a",
       enabled: true,
       configurationData: {
          featureAConfigPropertyA: {
             somePrperty: "whatever",
             anotherProperty: true
          },
          featureAConfigPropertyB: "some string"
       } 
    },
    {
       id: "feature-b",
       enabled: true,
       configurationData: {
          featureBConfigArrayPropertyA: ["some string"],
          featureBConfigPropertyB: [
             {
               "id": "some string",
               "name": "some string",
               "description": "some string",
               "enabled": true
             }
          ]
       } 
    }      
  ]
}
```

The actual structure of each feature is irrelevant. I am just trying to express this via json schema whereby the structure of configurationData for each feature is dependent on or dictated by the feature id value of its parent.

EDIT: I guess technically it doesnt need to be dependent on so long as either structure of configurationData is valid schema for that property on the feature schema itself. Also, the types in configurationData arent arbitrary, they would always be one of the two types for a given feature in this example.

This however needs to be structured in a way that can be expressed via Formly as I am using this to generate forms. In this case it would be an array of ObjectFieldTypes, one for feature a and one for feature b, which would enumerate the three properties and provide Input field types, until it got to configurationData at which point it would use an ObjectFieldType again, which would now be different for each field type.

The issue here is that 1) I'm not sure how to express this in json schema and 2) I can't use things like patternProperties with formly because the properties have to be explicitly defined in the json schema in order for formly to render the field types for each property. Although patternProperties would technically be valid schema in this case, if the schema doesn't define those properties, then the model in the valueChanges observable on the FormGroup just excludes them entirely. So I would end up with:

```
{
   features:[
     {
        id: "feature-a",
        enabled: true,
        configurationData: { } 
     },
     {
        id: "feature-b",
        enabled: true,
        configurationData: { } 
     }    
   ]
}
```

I have tried the if then else construct, but I cant tell if the schema is wrong or if formly just doesn't support this. I made a stack blitz for this below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g45ydm?file=src%2Fassets%2Fjson-schema%2Fif_then.json

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

Comment: I guess Im not exactly seeing how those apply. I played around with the if-then-else concept which kinda seems like it should work but I am unsure.

Comment: It appears formly doesnt support this, looking at the code here:
https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/blob/0257f744bf71b9f0b4ebd2cee1bcc538312618d4/src/core/json-schema/src/formly-json-schema.service.ts#L322

It seems to just merge the if then directly into the base schema which would only support a single conditional I think...

Comment: That doesn't sound good -- schemas can't be merged safely like that without losing some data.
I see you've reported that as a bug: https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/3066

Comment: I didn't report it as a bug, I reported it as a "question" it was changed by the maintainer to a feature request.